# Upload multiple images on anchor click

Tags: angularjs, anchor, ng-file-upload

I want to upload multiple images on **anchor tag** click. I am able to upload multiple images on **div** and **image** tags using [`ng-file-upload`](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Can anybody please suggest me how to upload multiple images on anchor tag click.

```
<a href=""><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
```

**Edited**

```
<a href="">
     <i class="fa fa-camera">
       <div  type="file"  ng-show="false" ngf-select  ng-model="profilePic.profileImageUrl"  ngf-max-size='2000000'>
       <img   ngf-src="profilePic.profileImageUrl[0]" ngf-default-src="../images/people/110/default_profile.png" height="100" width="100" class="fa fa-camera"></div>
      </i>
     </a>
```

Comment: Any effort in making that work?

Comment: @putvande, Obviously yes

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried in many ways, but was unsuccessful, Please see I have edited my code

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

See if this website could help you out.

I found also this code that you need  do is change the name of the file tag to array like

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple="multiple" class="btn btn-file"/>
```

and then you need to put the upload code into foreach as shown below

```
foreach($_FILES['userfile'] as $file)
{
   if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file)) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        .
        .
        .

      }
}
```

See if this could help you out. I'm new in the subject but I searched for a while and this could help you I think.

Comment: Hope this helps you some how